# Query to View new/updated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following to list the row count for all of my tables:

```
 select convert(varchar(30),object_name(id)) [Table Name], rows, ModifiedOn from sysindexes
where object_name(id) not like 'sys%' and indid = 1
order by object_name(id)
```

I confess that I found this somewhere and only have a conceptual idea of what it is doing.  But for my purposes, where I want to perform an application action and reverse engineer what happened in the database, it works well to identify new rows (I copy and paste before/after results into excel to compare).

Now, I would also like to know which tables have been updated.  On (almost) all of my tables there is a ModifiedOn column, so I am hoping I can add the max of this to my output, which will tell me when the table's contents were last updated.

I have no idea how to join these two, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to do a query and not, for example, use a trigger to notify you of changes (perhaps by updating a "data last modified" table)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest against this approach, as it is DB dependent and unreliable.

Creating an ON INSERT on ON UPDATE trigger it the correct solution, then in the trigger you can put the new or updated data into a separate table which you can query. Triggers are the tool to monitor changes in the database without doing anything in the applications using them.

Example trigger for 'after update' on table MY_TABLE(id, name):

```
CREATE TRIGGER mark_changes AFTER UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tracking_table VALUES "Change in table my_table", OLD.id, NEW.id
END$$
```

This assumes you have a table tracking_table(description, old_id, new_id)

Comment: Thanks - Unfortunately I don't think our DB guys want me adding anything.  Just a humble analyst trying to understand a database flow that has been long forgotten, so I was trying to find a way of getting some rough idea using only selects.

Comment: My answer is still correct... Btw, there is no (at least universal) way to check all changes in the database, unless there is some log, or some DBMS specific log table, that is not possible.